# New image is created but the old one is shown JS(AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, image

I have Ajax function

```
function getOutput() 
{

  var ajax = getRequest();
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<br/>";
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4)
      {
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }

  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<br/><img src=img/ajax-loader.gif><br/><br/>";
  ajax.open("GET", "graph_2.php", true);
  ajax.send(null);
}
```

HTML

```
<form >
  <input type="image" src=img/button.jpg class=mygtukas 
  onclick='getOutput(); return false;'>
</form>
<span id=output></span>
```

which calls PHP code to create a graph. First time it works fine, but when a user changes graph parameters and press a button again (page doesn't reload) it shows the old graph even dough there is  new graph created and saved in server.

Comment: did you update your `output` div when the image creation in complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of cache of the browser. A browsers saves a copy of the image on you computer on in a temp directory. Because this image has the same name and location as the previous version, it loads the image from the disk, which loads allot faster (no need to download it again)

The solution is very simple. Change the imagename to something variable. A widely used trick is to add a random value:

Instead of image.jpg, return image.jpg?_*randomStringHere*

The randomstring can be based on a few things. In php I like to use `uniqid()` because its always unique (unless someone can refresh faster then 1 milisec). Another method would be (as suggested in the comments below), is a timestamp. In php `time()` would suffice.

If you want a javascript solution, you can do something allong the lines of `image.src = image.src +'?'+ Math.random()`

---

It just occurred to me that it might be the AJAXcall itself. You can use the javascript suggestion stated above in your AJAXcall to make every call unique

[Math.random() documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)

Comment: One way to get round this is to add a unique querystring to the image. A timestamp is suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I was working on that part of my solution. I added a few methods of adding something unique to give some different approaches

Comment: I thought of that, but then I would have server full of diffrent images but I guess theres is nothing I can do about that. Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood! `image.jpg` and `image.jpg?somethingRandom` are exactly the same image! You only add the randomstring to the `src` to trick the browser that its another image, but it is the same one.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a cache issues, you can handle it the same way jquery `cache:false` handles it by adding a random value to your uri.

```
ajax.open("GET", "graph_2.php?_=" + Math.random() , true);
```

Comment: After I press a button it just sends me into blank page.

Comment: random() should be lowercased, using it uppercase gives an error that method `Random()` is undefined

Comment: Now it the same like before, first time ok, but after change in parameters still the same image.